# How to make IDs of components (Div, a, h1, etc) of a webpage Dynamic (variable?) using MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic

I am trying to do the following:
The object I give to the Viewpage has a list, I do a foreach in the HTML and I create a number of components. Now, I want the IDs of those components to somehow be linked to the object from the List.
(The reason I am trying to do this is because I want to show a button, when they press that button the shown content will change and they should see something else, I will use javascript to achieve this)

Therefor I am trying to make the id of those components dynamic, by for example stating
`id="button <%= item.id%>`" however this does not seem to work. I have searched alot on google but I haven't found a solution yet which is why I turn to you guys.

I'll link my code as well, I deleted some of the parts that were unnecessary (but added the javascript):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AlterPanel(thePanel) {
    var panel = document.getElementById("region"+thePanel);
    panel.style.display = 'block';
    var button = document.getElementById("button"+thePanel);
    button.style.display = 'none';}
</script>
<%foreach (TeamDTO team in Model.List.Teams)
     { %>
    <a id="button<%= team.Number %>" onclick="AlterPanel(<% team.Number%>)">
    Add member</a>
    <div Visible="false" id='region<%= team.Number %>' runat="server">
        Please select one: 
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(V => V.memberID, new SelectList(Model.members, "ID","Name")) %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

I eagerly await a reply and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your Queastion is:
-you have some "button DropDownList" pair, button is visiable, DropDownList is invisible, now if user click the button then DropDownList will showup.

OK, now your View maybe :

```
<%foreach (TeamDTO team in Model.List.Teams)
     { %>
    <a onclick="AlterPanel(<% team.Number%>)">
    Add member</a>
    <div id="region<%= team.Number %>" style="display:none">
        Please select one: 
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(V => V.memberID, new SelectList(Model.members, "ID","Name")) %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

I use JQuery in javascript part like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AlterPanel(thePanel) {
        $("#region" + thePanel.toString()).css("display", "block");
    }
</script>
```

Don't forget include the following file in View():

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>"></script>
```

if the answer is not what you want, let mt know and I can help you~ :)

Comment: Hey, thank you for trying to help me. The thing is, the javascript I have works, but it won't get to the page because it gives a compile error on the `id="region<%= team.Number %>"`, saying it is not a valid value for "id"

Comment: 1. Is the JavaScript in same View? (I mean you wrote the script in same View but not include the outside file)
2. Is each value of team.Number is unique?

Comment: 3.I think your source code line#10 "onclick="AlterPanel(<% team.Number%>)"> might be "onclick="AlterPanel(<%= team.Number%>)">, missing a equal sign.